# Nautlius: add mouse right-click action to compute MD5 sum

Tags: md5sum

Context: 16.04

How does one mouse right-click action to compute the MD5 sum of a file?

Answer (score 8):

You can work with a nautilus script.

1. Create the scripts directory if it does not yet exist

   ```sh
   mkdir -p ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/
   ```
2. Place your script into that directory and make it executable (`chmod +x <name_of_script>` or via your file manager: right-click file, properties). Any executable script you put there will be available under an entry "Scripts" in your right-click menu.

   In your script, you can use the variable `NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` to retrieve a newline-delimited list of selected files (i. e., one file path in case you selected a single file). You will also need to display the output: this can be done by piping the output of the command to zenity. This simple script will already cut it:

   ```sh
   #!/bin/bash
   set -eu -o pipefail
   md5sum "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" | zenity --text-info
   ```